# converting results of pickle file (json) to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pickle

I'm reading from a pickle file as follows:

```
data=pickle.load(open("name_ethnicities.pkl", "rb"))
```

it returns what looks like a json file that looks as follows:

```
  {'t creavalle': [{'scores': [{'ethnicity': 'Asian', 'score': '0.01'},
         {'ethnicity': 'GreaterAfrican', 'score': '0.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'GreaterEuropean', 'score': '0.99'}],
        'best': 'GreaterEuropean'},
       {'scores': [{'ethnicity': 'British', 'score': '0.99'},
         {'ethnicity': 'Jewish', 'score': '0.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'WestEuropean', 'score': '0.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'EastEuropean', 'score': '0.00'}],
        'best': 'British'}],
      'uyŏng yi': [{'scores': [{'ethnicity': 'Asian', 'score': '1.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'GreaterAfrican', 'score': '0.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'GreaterEuropean', 'score': '0.00'}],
        'best': 'Asian'},
       {'scores': [{'ethnicity': 'IndianSubContinent', 'score': '0.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'GreaterEastAsian', 'score': '1.00'}],
        'best': 'GreaterEastAsian'},
       {'scores': [{'ethnicity': 'Japanese', 'score': '0.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'EastAsian', 'score': '1.00'}],
        'best': 'EastAsian'}],
      'temple orme': [{'scores': [{'ethnicity': 'Asian', 'score': '0.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'GreaterAfrican', 'score': '0.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'GreaterEuropean', 'score': '1.00'}],
        'best': 'GreaterEuropean'},
       {'scores': [{'ethnicity': 'British', 'score': '1.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'Jewish', 'score': '0.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'WestEuropean', 'score': '0.00'},
         {'ethnicity': 'EastEuropean', 'score': '0.00'}],
        'best': 'British'}]
     }
```

I am trying to generate a dataframe from this, where it would return the name and the "best" result in each category separated by a comma. So for the above, the dataframe would look as such:

```
name               ethnicity
t creavalle        GreaterEuropean, British
uyong yi           Asian, GreaterEastAsian, EastAsian
temple orme        GreaterEuropean, British
```

And so on...

tried `pd.read_json` and that didn't work for me. Any suggestions how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.DataFrame([(k, ", ".join([x["best"] for x in v])) for k, v in data.items()], 
             columns=["name", "ethnicity"])
```

Explanation:

- items and k,v is the way to allow some operations to be done.
- See for example the output of `[(k, v) for k,v in data.items()]`
- You can see now that they are aligned, but the second column is not how you want it `pd.DataFrame([(k,v) for k, v in d.items()])`
- You want to select the best for each ethnicity column, and you can do that by `[x["best"] for x in v]` to make the result:

> ```
>           name                           ethnicity
> 0  t creavalle            GreaterEuropean, British
> 1     uyŏng yi  Asian, GreaterEastAsian, EastAsian
> 2  temple orme            GreaterEuropean, British
> ```